# [ETMC]OAuth issue when setup MC Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Hi I have a OAuth issue when setup  MC connect.

In MC, I have already connected system API user on connector setup page.
When I try to integrate individual user, there is a error message:
"There was an error communicating with Salesforce, verify your connected app is set up properly and try again."
At Force.com side, there are also an error message:
"Missing Consumer Key Parameter."

My package version is 5.496 (Updated 5/20/2016), there is not place to input password on MC side, I believe it's using OAuth. so do I have to input Consumer Key somewhere?

Another weird thing is that I try to disconnect system API user, also got an error :
"Something went wrong while attempting to clear integration. Please try again."

So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: If user credentials, check here [API user Credentials are invalid](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214332&language=en_US)

Comment: I found the reason. Even the deadlien is 25th this month, till now MC Connector don't support TLS1.1, couldn't believe that. http://help.marketingcloud.com/v5_tls_support

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing [these steps](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/post_configuration/):

**Update the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connected App**

1. In the Sales or Service cloud, click **Setup**
2. From Setup, enter Connected Apps in the Quick Find box, then select **Connected Apps**
3. Click **Salesforce Marketing Cloud**
4. Click **Edit**
5. Under Permitted Users, select **Admin approved users are pre-authorized**.
6. Under IP Relaxation, select **Relax IP restrictions**.
7. Under Refresh Token Policy, select **Immediately expire refresh token**.
8. Click **Save**

Comment: I tried this Post-Configuration, still don't work

Comment: Hi @ling - did you find a resolution for this at all? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing the same issue while integrating SFMC with SF at user level so here what I did -

There was already a MC user which was integrated with one of the SF user and i did not know which user so I was trying to integrate my MC user with the same SF user which is not possible as SF supports only one to one mapping. so i created a new user in SF and went back to MC and integrated my MC user with the SF user i just created and it worked. Hope this helps.